# HTML dialog closes automatically when file input is cancelled. How to prevent?

Tags: html, dialog

If you have a file input in a dialog, cancelling the file selection somehow closes the dialog. Why does this happen, and how can this be prevented?

```html
<dialog open>
  <input type="file">
</dialog>
```

**Edit**:

The dialog remains open (as expected) in Firefox. The dialog closes (unexpected) in Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually had the exact same problem. I suspect this is caused from the input triggering a `cancel` event when the user cancels the file selection. This `cancel` event bubbles up to the dialog where it mistakenly assumes it is for itself and thus prematurely closes. This issue seems to only appear in Chromium browsers as this behavior does not happen in Firefox as you had mentioned.

When such a case occurs, the `cancel` event for the dialog is fired, but the event has a target of the input. This is useful in detecting if the dialog is about to close prematurely, and raise a flag in the form of a boolean variable.

```js
const dialog = document.getElementById("dialog");
let prematurelyClosed = false;

dialog.addEventListener("cancel", (e) => {
  if(e.target !== dialog)
     prematurelyClosed = true;
  // or simply prematurelyClosed = e.target !== dialog
})
```

That way, when dialog's `close` event is called, we can check if the flag is raised. If it is, we know that the dialog is about the close when it shouldn't be and prevent it. However, it seems that the only way to "prevent" it is from @underflow's answer where we need to immediately reopen the modal. I have not found any other way than this. With this method at least, we only need to reopen it during this specific case, and properly close it for everything else, like if a user presses <kbd>Esc</kbd> or if, say, a button calls `dialog.close()`.

```js
dialog.addEventListener("close", (e) => {
  if(prematurelyClosed){
    dialog.showModal();
    prematurelyClosed = false;
  }
})
```

So in the end, I ended up with this which solved my case and can hopefully help yours.

```js
const dialog = document.getElementById("dialog");
let prematurelyClosed = false;

dialog.addEventListener("cancel", (e) => {
  if(e.target !== dialog)
     prematurelyClosed = true;
  // or simply prematurelyClosed = e.target !== dialog
})

dialog.addEventListener("close", (e) => {
  if(prematurelyClosed){
    dialog.show();
    prematurelyClosed = false;
  }
})
```

```html
<dialog open id="dialog">
  <input type="file">
  <button onclick="dialog.close()">Close</button>
</dialog>
```

Comment: Nice work around!

Comment: I notice the `cancel` event object has `cancelable: false` which is presumably why calling `e.preventDefault()` in the dialog's `cancel` event handler does not prevent it from closing. I presume you tried this also. I've also tried handling `cancel` on the file input and either `preventDefault()` or `stopPropagation()` but nothing I've tried prevents the dialog from receiving that uncancelable `cancel` event and closing, do you have any further insight into how to achieve this?

Comment: @Neek Sorry, but I don't have any further insight into this, sadly. I had tried canceling the event on both the dialog and input, even going as far as to try `stopImmediatePropagation()`  but to no success. On a side note, it seems that this is indeed [a bug in chromium](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1442824) and [has had a patch for some time now.](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/de5fbde391c2cf6ddf7b165a74da71b858466d39%5E%21/) Although I have no clue when we'll start seeing it on browsers but hopefully soon.

Comment: @Urban you're a star, I hadn't found that bug report in my investigations last week.  On your tip, I downloaded `Version 117.0.5855.0 (Developer Build) (64-bit)` (via `$ npx @puppeteer/browsers install chromium@latest`) and the bug seems fixed.  The file input gets a 'cancel' event, and the dialog receives a 'cancel' event, but no 'close' event. With current behaviour, the `cancel` event received by the file input and the dialog elements (not sure if it's the same Event object) still has `cancelable:false`. Will wait for stable release and ignore for now.

Answer (score 0):

Found a good way to keep the dialog/modal opened after having clicked on Cancel or <kbd>Esc</kbd>

```js
const dialog = document.getElementById("dialog");

dialog.addEventListener('close', (e) => {
  dialog.showModal();
});

const closeButton = document.querySelector(".close");
closeButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  dialog.style.display = "none";
});
```

```html
<dialog id="dialog" open>
  <input type="file" />
  <button class="close">Close</button>
</dialog>
```

In this specific case, the best way to manually close the modal will be through CSS.

Comment: How can you then close this dialog?

Comment: Added the code to close it manually

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing this same issue with an Angular app I was working on. Essentially the cancel event from the input was bubbling up to calling component. I solved it by using a host listener on the input component to listen for and stop the propagation of the event up to my other component.

```js
@HostListener('cancel', ['$event'])
  onCancel(event: Event){ 
    console.log('Cancel host listener.'); 
    event.stopImmediatePropagation(); 
  };
```